# SCSS fitting an image in a circle via cropping top and bottom

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this code, which I inherited from a UI/UX guy, who I am no longer in contact with.

This code is for the display of pictures. It takes the pictures and squishes it in to a 1x1 ratio and then displays it in a circle.

I would like it to instead, not squish, but crop the top and bottom or sides to make the picture a 1x1 ratio and then display it in the circle.

```
@mixin avatar($size:40px) {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: $size/2;
}
%avatar-border-shadow {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(#000, 0.4);
}
.avatar {
  @include avatar(40px);

  @include mod('lg') {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    @include avatar(128px);
    @extend %avatar-border-shadow;
  }

  @include mod('xl') {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    @include avatar(160px);
    @extend %avatar-border-shadow;
  }

  @include mod('settings') {
    cursor: pointer
  }
}
```

I have tried adding code like:

```
...
  @include mod('lg') {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
....
```

But it seems to have no effect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The file's name is avatars.scss

Edit:

This is the 'html/ruby'

```
img.avatar--lg(src=display_medium_avatar(current_user))
```

Comment: Why not just create square images server side? CSS is for styling, not image manipulation. You are asking for an ugly hack.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that this is not an easy fix, I am not used to styling. I'll look into working with the upload code.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to put image as a `background-image: url('...');` and in styles file add `background-size: cover;` to avatar-div.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to implement this.

Comment: instead of <img class="avatar--lg" src = "...> to <img class="avatar--lg" background-image: url(... > ?

Comment: I am having trouble implementing this in the .html.slim file. Would I have to make the the avatars into <body> tags?

Answer (score 0):

There is also the possibility of making use of a class with an `img` element utilizing `overflow: hidden` and setting the img height to 100%, to make sure the circle area is covered. See JSFiddle demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/dc50gd9q/1/.

This solves the same problem for users who do not necessarily have direct access or find it less "clean" to add style attributes to classes in order to inject a `background-image`.